# Functional programming in OOP language

Tags: java, oop, functional-programming

immutable objects are OK, but, are OK **non-final local references**?

In other words, next code snippet can be represented as written in functional style?

```
Employee e = new Employee("Lex", 24, 250);
e = Employee.setName(e, "Vasili");
e = Employee.setAge(e, 12);
e = Employee.setSalary(e, 2500);
Employee.log(e);
```

P.S. here all `Employee` methods are static, setters are factory methods that returns new instances.

Comment: `e0`, `e1`, `e2` are all undefined. Using `setX` and `setY` as method names here is misleading. Perhaps name them `createWithX` and `createWithY`.

Comment: what do you mean with OK?

Comment: Every fluent API is based at `this` keyword - main difference of `OOP` and `FP` languages. So, I avoid this to write really functional code.

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise?

Comment: Sorry, initial post contained mistakes. @payloc OK means "how in pure FP language it's done".

Comment: @biziclop No, I simply want to know `java` better.

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. Why do you make an employee called "Lex" and then rename them to "Vasili"?

Comment: To simulate *pure functional coding* in Java, all local variables must be `final`. Parameters too.

Comment: An immutable style would probably be `new Employee("Lex", 24, 250).withName("Vasili").withAge(12).withSalary(2500)`, with the `with` methods each returning a new `Employee` object.

Comment: @byxor Examples are meaninless, main here is coding style.

Comment: @Andreas - can you explain, why local variable must be final? Objects must be, but why reference?

Comment: @LouisWasserman You mean that object must have `with` methods and they must be invoked using `this` (dot) reference? I think that `this` keyword is not-suitable for FP.

Comment: @LexUshakov In pure functional languages, there are no "variables". There are names which refer to values, but you cannot change the value. In imperative programming terms, all variables are constants, i.e. not *variable* / varying / changeable at all. That is why, to *simulate* the same behavior in Java, make parameters and local variables `final`, so they cannot be re-assigned / updated / modified.

Comment: @LexUshakov Why would you think that?  That sort of fluent style is perfectly normal in functional programming.

Comment: Your first line is "functional" in that it creates a single value, but everything else changes the value you already created.

Comment: @PaulJohnson, there is an object and a reference to it. As I understand it's completely different things. Object must be immutable, - it's clear. But why reference must be immutable too?

Comment: Also, we speak about local variables, not object fields.

Comment: local in the sense of a *method-local* right? If so, if you don't escape the reference (unlike your `Employee.log(e)`), than there is no need to make them final/immutable. But if you do, someone might change the properties of your `e`, via the reference. Re-assining the reference (for example) via `e = new Employee()...` will have zero effect on your local reference...

Comment: @LexUshakov, in functional programming there are no objects or references, there are only values, and values don't change. You don't change the value of 4 in a program, so if you have said that x=4 then you don't change x either, because that would be just the same as changing the value of 4. The first line says that e = Employee "Lex" etc. Then you change e to be Employee "Vasili". So is e Lex or Vasili? It can't be both. In FP there is no concept of "flow of control" in which variables have different values at different times.

Comment: When your static factory method create and return new objects, as you say, then these method do already allow a functional style without mutable variables: `Employee e = Employee.setName( Employee.setAge(Employee.setSalary(new Employee("Lex", 24, 250), 2500), 12), "Vasili");` but it should be obvious that it would become more readable when you swap the order of the parameters…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know anything about `Haskell`, but I believe you are trying to achieve something like this:

```
Employee e = new Employee("Lex")
    .setAge(25)
    .setSalary(2500)
    .setGender(Gender.Male);
```

This is just a result of `chaining` functions in the following way

```
public Employee setParam(param){
   this.param = param;
   return this;
}
```

but the methods are **not** static, they belong to the instance.

Also there would be no need to pass the instance as parameter.

---

Also:

- `this` isn't a required keyword; in my example above, the two parameters have the same name, so without `this` the code would basically re-assign param's value to itself. If the parameters had a different name `this` is not required. Yet returning `this` is necessary as it represent a reference to the current instance.

E.g:

```
public Employee setParam(String param) {
    parameter = param; // parameter is a field in class Employee
    return this; // this "this", is still necessary
}
```

- `final` variables

May limit you on what you are trying to achieve with your style

```
final Employee e = Employee.setName(e, "Name"); // invalid, e is unkown

// ----------------

final Employee e;
e = Employee.setName(e, "Name"); // invalid, e may not be initialized

// ----------------

final Employee e;
e = Employee.setName("Name"); // valid

// ----------------

final Employee e = null;
e = Employee.setName(e, "Name"); // invalid. e was already initalized to null

// ----------------

final Employee e = Employee.setName("Name"); // valid
e = Employee.setName("Name2"); // invalid, final variable already initialized
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I already know it. So, in  other words, it's impossible to make fluent API without `this` keyword, right?

Comment: @LexUshakov `this` is not required, let me update my answer

Comment: When non-static methods are used, they, simply speaking, are binded to some struct via hidden `this` link. Imho this is essential, main feature of `OOP` langs.

Answer (score 2):

Since this question is tagged 'java', I assume the question is on the FP practices (namely, immutability) in Java.

Today's good practice in Java is to use either a builder:

```
Employee e = Employee.builder()
                     .surname("Lex")
                     .age(24)
                     .name("Vasili")
                     .salary(2500)
                     .build();
```

or a static constructor:

```
Employee e = Employee.of("Vasili", "Lex", 24, 2500);
```

In both cases, the "classic" constructor should be declared private to ensure that the object can't be instantiated and made available to the client in inconsistent state.

Object mutators should then return the new object:

```
Employee.of("Vasili", "Lex", 24, 2500)  // creates an object
        .updateName("Sergey")           // returns 1st modified copy
        .updateSalary(3500);            // returns 2nd modified copy based on 1st copy
```

Following these practices, the need for non-final local references often vanishes.

A very popular example is the [Date and Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Now, on using mutable local variables. That's ok, but the code can be shortened and made more expressive using method chaining. Trying to chain the static methods as-is will not look very elegant:

```
Employee e = setSalary(setAge(setName(new Employee("Lex", 24, 250), "Vasili"), 12), 2500);
```

As an attempt to emulate a monad, one can wrap the object in some monad-like container which defines a bind method that accepts a function, which will accept the object stored in monad and return some result, which will again be wrapped in a monad. A simple example will look like this:

```
static class Employee {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public long salary;
}

static class Monad<T> {
    private final T value;

    private Monad(T value) { this.value = value; }

    public static <T> Monad<T> of(T value) {
        return new Monad<>(value);
    }

    public T getValue() { return value; }

    public Monad<T> bind(UnaryOperator<T> operator){
        return of(operator.apply(value));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Employee value = Monad.of(new Employee())
                          .bind(e -> {e.name = "Lex"; return e; })
                          .bind(e -> {e.age = 24; return e; })
                          .bind(e -> {e.salary = 2500; return e; })
                          .getValue();
}
```

But this can be done with core Java since version 8 - [Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) can do this and much more:

```
Stream.of(new Employee())
      .map(e -> {e.name = "Lex"; return e; })
      .map(e -> {e.age = 24; return e; })
      .map(e -> {e.salary = 2500; return e; })
      .findFirst()
      .get();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, @jihor! In your examples mutable object is stored - but it can be replaced by immutable one with static methods references?

Comment: Can you help to understand, why next code doesn't work? https://pastebin.com/DMN18EQv

Comment: @LexUshakov `map()` method on stream of `T` expects `Function<? super T, ?>`. The working line will look as `.map((e) -> Employee.setName(e, "Vasilii"))`.

Answer (score 1):

It is similar to that in the terms that every function returns new item, in many FP languages (e.g. Haskell) you even are not able to update the value, just create new one:

```hs
let myBook = beginBook "Haskell"
let myBook' = addChapter (Chapter "Intro" ["Hello","World"]) myBook
```

So here `beginBook` function will return a book and then `addChapter` will return another book with some fields modified.

Comment: But are you allowed to re-`let` variable `myBook` in Haskell? That's what the question is asking, i.e. can a local variable be updated.

Comment: @Andreas, no, in `haskell` it's definitely impossible. Here `myBook` and `myBook'` are functions definitions, not data structure as `java` class is.

Answer (score 1):

Will something like this work for you (ignore the bad use of `Optional` and `ifPresent` we can replace it with something more meaningful)?

```
    Optional.of( new Employee("Lex", 24, 250) )
    .map( e -> Employee.setName(e, "Vasili") )
    .map( e -> Employee.setAge(e, 12) )
    .map( e -> Employee.setSalary(e, 2500) )
    .ifPresent( e -> Employee.log(e) );
```